# How many pairs of integers satisfy a cubic diophantine equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I need to find the number of pairs of integers (a,b) that satisfy the diophantine equation $a^3-117b^3 = 5$.

I know that I need to use modulo arithmetic somehow, I just don't know exactly how. I think it has something to do with $mod$ $9$, but to be honest I don't really know. Anything that could help me would be much appreciated.

Comment: $a^3\equiv5\pmod9$ has no solutions; $a^3\equiv 0, 1, $ or $8\pmod9$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any n, if (a, b) is a solution of your equation, then (a mod n, b mod n) is a solution of your equation mod n. Your equation mod 9 is $a^3 = 5$ (because 117 = 9 *13). You can compute a^3 mod 9 for a = 0,1,...,8.

You get :
\begin{align}
&a&a^3\\
&0&0\\
&1&1\\
&2&8\\
&3&0\\
&4&1\\
&5&8\\
&6&0\\
&7&1\\
&8&8\\
\end{align}
As you can see, this equation has no solutions which means your original equation doesn't have any solutions.